# Designing an app that emails out a barcode

Tags: iphone

A client wants me to write an app, the primary goal of the app is not marketing but I would say the secondary goal is marketing.

So the app allows the user to select names from the address book and then it sends out a rota to everyone.  It also sends out a meeting request.

The problem is it has a voucher for a consumer product attached as an image and it has the company's logo etc in the emails and meetings request.

is this allowed?

5.6 - Apps cannot use Push Notifications to send advertising, promotions, or direct marketing of any kind

2.13 - Apps that are primarily marketing materials or advertisements will be rejected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An email isn't a push notification - why not just send emails rather than pushes. No issue then.

If it isn't primarily, only secondarily, marketing, then I guess it is OK with Apple?

Seems like it is bothering you though. Good thing iOS developers can pretty much choose what they do these days eh?